# can't reattach to screen

Tags: screen, cron

I've been having problems with screen (the terminal command).
If I type `screen -ls` it gives me:

> No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.

For `screen -r` I get:

> There is no screen to be resumed.

What I did was to put `@reboot screen -d -m /path/to/script` in crontab, my shell script starts a java process.

My `htop` shows both the java and the screen command PID.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.1.
I am still not sure what is causing the issue, but this will re-create the fifo/socket and allow you to reattach to the screen session.

```
kill -CHLD <PID_OF_SCREEN>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps screen is being created by a user other than `root` and is thus not in the `/var/run/screen/S-root` directory, and is instead in the `/var/run/screen/S-username` directory.

You can try to add the screen to your root crontab instead of a user's crontab. Example:

`sudo crontab -u root -e`

Comment: If I said that `screen -ls` shows "No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root." it means I am logged in as root when I am trying this stuff out. I am NOT logged in as ANOTHER user and trying to get access to a root screen, I am logged in as root, and trying to get access to an existing root screen session.

Comment: Well I feel smart. I wrote my answer backwards. Fixed it so it makes sense (in case this would be a solution for others finding this page from google).